# How to fix an error with opening the API in the browser?

Tags: django, docker, docker-compose

I am developing a project for react + django, using docker, docker launches a backend application at address 0.0.0.0:8000, 3 days ago everything worked fine, but today there was such an error.
[image]
At the same time, requests through postman pass successfully.

File entrypoint.sh
[image]

File docker-compose
[image]

Logs docker
[image]

I tried to give a different address, switch to the last commit, change ports in the hosts file. The container itself starts successfully, but there is no access from outside. I suspect that the matter is that the host is blocked, but I do not know how to check it.

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)  Can you [edit] the question to include the details necessary to reproduce the issue and the actual error logs, as plain text and not images?

Comment: What URL are you actually connecting to?  If you say Postman works, what is different between your Postman and browser setups?  It looks like your original `docker-compose.yml` might try to publish to a host port `${BACKEND_PORT}`, does that port number match your URLs?